# AngularJS nested ng-repeats with a single index?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using Angular 1.0.7, how can I specify a single index for nested `ng-repeat`s, so that each item on the inner arrays get's a consecutive index value? (i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3 and so on for all elements in all inner arrays)

To **illustrate**:

```
<ul>
    <li ng:repeat="item in arr1">
        <ul>
            <li ng:repeat="child in item.children">{{consecutiveIndex++}}</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I tried to achieve it in the following manner:

```
var cindex= -1;
$scope.cindex= function () {
  console.log('cindex', cindex);
  return ++cindex;
};
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li ng:repeat="item in arr1">
        <ul>
            <li ng:repeat="child in item.children">{{index()}}</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I am getting quite exotic AngularJS errors using this (believe me, you don't wanna know).

I have also found out (following the console output), that even for an array with a mere 4 elements, ng-repeat hit my `cindex()` function over 80 times. Meaning instead of 0, 1, 2 and 3 - I got 84, 85, 86 and 87.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't depend on your `{{index()}}` to be called a fixed amount of times. Whenever angular decides to dirty check a scope it will run all the bindings.

You can generate the value based on other indexes. [Demo plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VMb2SjkLdZxbJNVkc1uI?p=preview)

**HTML**

```
<body ng:controller="MainCtrl">
  <ul>
     <li ng:repeat="item in arr1">
        <ul ng:init="parentIndex = $index">
           <li ng:repeat="child in item.children">{{getConsecutiveIndex(parentIndex, $index)}}</li>
        </ul>
     </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.arr1 = [{children:[0,1,2,3]}, {children:[4,5]}, {children:[6,7,8]}];

  $scope.getConsecutiveIndex = function(parentIndex, $index) {
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < parentIndex; i += 1) {
      total += $scope.arr1[i].children.length;
    }
    return total + $index;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, for sharing this. I had a similar requirement, nested ng-repeats, but needed to know which iteration of the outer $index I was in. I was able to move the ng-init to the same tag as the outer ng-repeat. FYI.

Answer (score 1):

The [ngRepeat directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat) provides a special `$index` property which should suit your needs. It is zero-based and is exposed on the local scope of each template instance.

Try this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng:repeat="item in arr1">
        <ul>
            <li ng:repeat="child in item.children">{{$index + 1}}</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```