# Generate tag id from angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

> I need to create a html structure as follows:
>
> ```
> <ul>
> <li id="r1_1">Root node 1
>     <ul>
>       <li id="child_node_1">Child node 1</li>
>       <li id="child_node_2">Child node 2</li>
>       <li id="child_node_3">Child node 3</li>
>     </ul>
>   </li>
>   <li id="r1_4">Root node 2
>     <ul>
>       <li id="child_node_4">Child node 4</li>
>       <li id="child_node_5">Child node 5</li>
>     </ul></li>
> </ul>   </div>
> ```
>
> My issue is that i am unable to generate the id indexes. i need to do
>   this using angularjs. can someone please help? I am very new to angularjs.

Comment: Use `ng-repeat` and `$index` - hard to help without the data structure.

Comment: Maybe you should ask yourself why you need to generate those ids...

Comment: I am using a third party JQuery plugin that requires this kind of structure :)

Comment: Sorry guys, My bad! I corrected the id duplication.

Comment: Here is exactly the same problem solved in a nice way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19127193/965907

Answer (score -1):

As tymeJV mentioned, you can use ng-repeat and $index to do it.

Here is a working plunker with an example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/S4H08rHgpQlGhY18VkNP?p=preview

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="root in rootNodes" id="someprefix_{{calculateRootId($index)}}">
    {{root.node}} calculated id: someprefix_{{calculateRootId($index)}}
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in root.items" id="someprefix_{{$index +1}}">Child node {{$index + 1}}</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Edit: updated plunkr to meet your requirement, note that the use of a helper function to calculate the id is very useful, BUT it would be nice to give your array items (roots and childs) an Id variable that is previously calculated on your controller and simply bind to it.

The above solution works, but I would not recommend it. I like to separate the logic from the view as much as I can, and it is a best practice to do it. Having said that, check out this other example: http://plnkr.co/edit/QsnZFlCx347nnSnkFj7W?p=preview

Here the logic of the id generation is all in the controller, so the view can bind directly to the calculated ids, and that also make it easier to change or customize even further that logic if necessary:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="root in rootNodes" id="{{root.id}}">
    {{root.name}} id: {{root.id}}
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in root.items" id="item.id">{{item.name}} id: {{item.id}}</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: What about the root node? I need the root node Id to be the sum of child elements of the previous root node